# Node.js async taking too long to execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I've got my array of queries

```
var array = [ 'UPDATE EVALUATION SET mark = "16" WHERE id_eval = "21" AND id_usr = "125"', 
              'UPDATE EVALUATION SET mark = "9" WHERE id_eval = "22" AND id_usr = "125"', 
              'UPDATE EVALUATION SET mark = "8" WHERE id_eval = "34" AND id_usr = "125"' 
            ]
```

However, when I try to execute them all at once with async, my web page says `Waiting for localhost...` and it keeps on loading forever. What am I doing wrong?

```
async.forEach(array, function(query, callback) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        callback();
    });
}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Whether your connection is established??

Comment: It my be that the database server you are connecting to can only handle a maximum number of queries at a time.

Comment: You should do `return callback(err)` in your first function to propagate errors, and only handle them in the last function. As it is now, any error in  `connection.query` will never propagate to the last function.

Comment: Also, check your console for errors.

Comment: @Frxstrem it doesn't display any errors

Comment: @Subburaj When I reload the page, I can see the changes that I wanted being made, meaning that executing of the queries is correct

Comment: First: You *should* really do a `return callback(err)` if something failed and log your errors in the last block. Second: Do not forget to call `res.end()` or similar to quit HTTP connection.

Comment: @coyer It doesn't display any errors to me. As for `res.end()`, I am rendering to another page after the queries, not sure where to put it

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code? how do you handle the response? In addition, even though you claim that there aren't any errors, I strongly agree with @coyer. Currently, your code *will* get stuck and never return if any of the queries will return an error.

Comment: @rockasaurus you may place your complete code here. Usually you have to leave your code at some point (calling res.end() or a callback in the last final-block)

Comment: After my code there is just `res.redirect('/next-page');
I've never done async before, so I am not sure how to handle the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you return the response after the `forEach` callback is called:

```
async.forEach(array, function(query, callback) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        callback();
    });
}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    res.redirect('/next-page');
});
```

That way, the redirection will occur only at the end of all the queries.

Some things you should verify:

- Verify you didn't call `res.end()` or `res.redirect()` or anything similar before the above code.
- Verify that your DB `query` method actually expect only 2 arguments: query and callback, and not anything in between (e.g. the query parameters).
- Verify this piece of code is actually called when you expect it. Try debugging the request all the way.
- Currently there's no real error handling here. You should consider returning an HTTP error if something went wrong. This should also help you debugging this code in the future.

Comment: Same as before - page loads forever and no errors in the log

Comment: OK. Please edit your question, to show the *full* relevant code, from the request to the response. It's hard to guess what's wrong with your code without seeing it. And please verify the assumptions in my answer are correct, mainly the ones regarding `connection.query` number of arguments and the fact that this code is actually being executed.

Comment: It's ok, I've solved it, your solution is the best, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a request handler like this:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});
```

Your browser holds the connection until `res.end`was called!

In your environment it should look somethinge like

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  // ... 
  async.forEach(array, function(query, callback){
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        // you may do some work here but leave it *alyways* via callback!
        callback(err);
    });
  }, function(err){
    if(err){ // this may be errors from above
      return console.log(err);
    }
    // Exit here !
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('All done.\n');
  });
});
```

...or a bit cleaner

```
function doSomeDatabaseUpdates(onFinished) {
  var array = [...];
  async.forEach(array, function(query, callback){
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        // you may do some work here but leave it *alyways* via callback!
        callback(err);
    });
  }, 
  function IGetCalledAfterAboveCallbackWereExecuted(err){
    if(err){ // this may be errors from above
      return console.log(err);
    }
    // Exit here !
    onFinished();
  });
}


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  // ... do some work

  if (doSomeUpdated === true) {
    doSomeDatabaseUpdates(function calledAfterUpdates() {
      res.end("updates something");
    });
  } else {
    res.end("nothing to do");
  }

});
```

Comment: Same as before - page loads forever and no errors in the log